# Question regarding "h" in differentiation via first principles

Tags: calculus

[image]

Here at the second last step he factors out $h$ from the numerator. Then cancels the $h$ at the denominator. He then says since $h$ approaches $0$ we consider it as $0$ or something that's really small so much so that it won't affect our answer much, and so we are left with $2x$.

My question is, throughout the equation we say $\lim h\to 0$, its not just at the very last step. So why don't we just consider $h$ to be $0/a$ very small number from the very beginning (I know this will mean we are essentially dividing by $0$ from the very start which gives undefined), but there has to be some sense of continuity here, what's the point of just considering $h$ as $0$ at the very end.

I know some of you will say well $h$ isn't $0$ actually it's something approaching $0$ i.e. something very close to $0$, even so my point still stands, in fact a new issue arrises, if I assumed $h$ to be very small and not $0$ from the very start (like I previously stated above) I won't get undefined but I would instead get a very large number since $h$ being close to $0$ at the numerator would mean the result is big, for example $2÷(1/10000000000000000000000000000000)$ represents essentially the same logic I'm trying to say.

Comment: If you assume $h=0$ from the beginning then all derivatives will equal $\frac{0}{0}$. Also, this is not derivation from first principles. Have you seen the epsilon-delta definition of a limit?

Comment: Yeah that is exactly my point so why do we consider h to be 0 or approaching 0 throughout. How is this not differentiation from first principles?The whole vide was differentiation via first principles. Also no i have not heard of that definition of a limit

Comment: It may help to actually plug into each formula at each step, a very small value of $h$, like $0.0001$, and possibly a concrete value of $x$, like $3$, to make things very concrete. *Both* the numerator and denominator will be really small, and those smallnesses will cancel each other out to get a value close to $2x$.

Comment: @jjose You should learn what a limit actually is before drawing conclusions from differentiation by hand waving.

Answer (score 1):

You're wary about the whole $\frac{0}{0}$ thing, and that's perfectly valid. However, what you should notice is:

- Whenever $h \neq 0$, the division *is* valid, and it *does* give the result $2x + h$.
- As $h$ approaches $0$ from below (i.e. if we look at values of $h$ that are negative but getting closer to zero, like $-0.01, -0.001, -0.0001, \ldots$) then $2x + h \rightarrow 2x$.
- Similarly, as $h$ approaches $0$ from above, we also get $2x + h \rightarrow 2x$.

Because we are getting the same limit in both directions, we can say that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{2xh + h^2}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (2x + h) = 2x$. And this is all fine, because when we take the limit we can ignore the point itself and so there is never any actual division by zero.

If you arrange things slightly differently, you get $\frac{2xh + h^2}{h} = 2x \frac{h}{h} + \frac{h^2}{h}$, and maybe it's a little easier to see what's happening here - if $h$ is some small value, then $\frac{h}{h} = 1$, and $\frac{h^2}{h} = h$ is going to be small. So in other words the value of $h$ doesn't actually change the first term, and the second term is the bit that's going to go to zero.

This is a very common manipulation with limits, especially in calculus - if a function behaves nicely everywhere *except* the point we're taking the limit to, we're allowed to ignore that particular bad behaviour and just pay attention to what the function is doing in a so-called "punctuated neighbourhood".

It's also important to notice that this only happens specifically because we're cancelling $\frac{h}{h}$. If we had a different kind of zero-over-zero expression we might not be so lucky - compare what happens as $h$ approaches $0$ in the cases of $\frac{h}{h}, \frac{h^2}{h}, \frac{h}{h^2}$.